# How much Traffic from google does a Pagerank X generates ?

Tags: google, pagerank, traffic

Yesterday was the birthday of my website, I have achieved the milestone of an average of 400 visitors from Google, yet my pagerank = 0

Do you guys have an idea on how much traffic generates PR1 , 2 , 3 etc ... 
Please share your data

Answer (score 1):

There is no correlation between traffic and PageRank.

Google cannot track traffic for most sites and has wisely keep traffic out of the metric mix. Having said that, there are some metrics to pay attention to: search engine result page (SERP) click-through rate (CTR), Bounce Rate (back to SERP), apparent time spent on page, apparent time spent on site. Google cannot fully determine how much time is spent on a site or page, but can extrapolate an approximation based on some metrics. What is most important from a SERP point of view is the Impression/CTR/Bounce Rate ratios. Keep this in mind.

In fact, do not look for Google to issue PageRank scores. Google has retired the PageRank metric as it applies to sites. SiteRank replaces PageRank and is not a publicized metric. The simple answer is that it caused confusion and complaints.

SiteRank is related to the bulk of the metrics that Google keeps. A major part of this is TrustRank. I just happen to be creating (as we speak) a webpage that lists the metrics that effect TrustRank and it is a significant list of metrics.

If you are interested in improving SiteRank, you will will need to focus on Trust metrics for your site. Part of this is site age, quality registrar, quality host, contact information (use mark-up), good up-time ratio, remaining off of black lists, and so on. The list is far too large for this format.

As well, use trajectory to your advantage. Part of this is adding and updating content (freshness), creating high quality inbound back links, high quality organic inbound back links (created by real humans - not you) - you will not have much control over this, planning and covering topics/sub-topics that broaden your keyword reach, social signals (I like Twitter), and so on. Keep one eye on toxic links and very cautiously and selectively disavow particularly bad links. Generally this is an action that should only be taken under extreme conditions.

There are two things you do not worry about: PageRank, and keyword density. Yes. Use keywords and plan your keywords carefully, but do not narrowly focus your content too much by optimizing for too few keywords. Long-tail keywords offer more traffic in the long run. Over optimizing a site for select keywords, limits the opportunity to rank well for long-tail keywords.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that far from "retiring" Pagerank, Google still uses it heavily.   They think they can have fewer black hat SEOs if they give out less data.  So now they just are publicizing the numbers anymore.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I meant only from the public's eye. I use the term SiteRank because that is closer to what Google actually uses the older metric for. PageRank as a **term** that applies to the site was a horrible idea and now that the focus is on page by page PageRank, the term, as it was originally used, was causing problems. PageRank/SiteRank as it applies to the sites internally, is still very much used but I do no think that the public PageRank rates have been updated in quite some time. Or mine would have gone lower... ;-)

Comment: Just a note too: PageRank (PR) is based on a "page" and not the whole domain. You can have a PR 0 on 999/1000 URLs of your site, with a PR 10 for that 1 single page. Of course we know PR 10 is almost impossible to achieve, even Google itself has very few PR 10 pages :) SiteRank+TrustRank is a better classification although Google has never released "SR+TR" stats (and never will). The closest thing is Moz Domain Authority.

Comment: @dhaupin I must be much older than you... ;-) Google started out with page rank pertaining to the whole site only. It has only been in the past few years that you have been able to see page rank on a page by page basis which is preferred. What is being retired, is page rank as an indicator for the entire site. Perhaps I should make my answer clearer. I remember looking at a schema and page rank was not represented. A cloud for trust rank and a cloud for site rank with some overlap. So I took page rank as being calculated on a nearly real-tame basis or exists outside of the index.

Comment: @closetnoc My first site was in 1993. Better to forget the past when it comes to the good ol days. It's def turning into strict trust rank...I estimate by 2016 all the standard calculations for "X authority" will be out the door. Of course we will have other issues then as it's easy to get trust yet impossible for Big Bro to predict website-thought-crime haha.

Comment: @dhaupin You are right about establishing trust, however, some factors such as site age along with registrar, host, and network quality metrics cannot be established other than by choosing wisely and waiting. Some trust metrics are established *over time*. I advocate establishing trust *first* (the best you can) then rank second. Keep your nose clean and do good work and SERP performance should be where it should be.